# Double a time span in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, date, timespan

I've got three `int`'s:

- minutes
- seconds
- tens (seconds/10)

Now, I am able to format it like this as a `NSString`: MM:SS.TT

But: How can I double the time span and print it out? I have to use something like `%` to do it the basic way.

Is there a smarter option in Xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will achieve that for you. I've split out the various steps to show how it works, but you could/should probably condense this to suit your purposes

```
// Assumes NSInteger values already exist for minutes, seconds and tens

NSTimeInterval span = (minutes * 60) + seconds + ((double)tens / 10.0);

// Double the time-interval
NSTimeInterval twiceSpan = span * 2.0;

// Determine the components
minutes = floor(twiceSpan / 60.0);
seconds = floor(twiceSpan - (minutes * 60.0));
tens = round((twiceSpan - (minutes * 60) - seconds) * 10.0);

// Form a string to show the time as m:s.t where the seconds value is always two digits
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i:%02i.%i", minutes, seconds, tens];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, the correct Cocoa unit is the [`NSTimeInterval`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW69).  Which is just a double that contains the number of seconds - so you would add all the above up into that one `NSTimeInterval`, multiply it by 2, and then you could express any pretty printing with the `[NSDate initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:]` and `[... dateWithString:]` and the like in [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you're only ever expressing just the interval, I don't know why you wouldn't just keep it in the NSInterval (or just the number of seconds) and express it as `(seconds/60):(seconds%60).(tens)` or whatever, that seems pretty straightforward to me.  Keeping it split up into 3 ints seems awkward to me.

Comment: You can't do `%` on a `NSTimeInterval` since it's a `double`. +1 on the rest.

Comment: Agreed, better to keep the times as NSTimeInterval whenever you can, but if he has to have them as separate ints...

Comment: @DarkDust - Good point. I'd cast it to an `(int)` or `(long)` in the process before applying the integer math anyway, since I would want to drop the fractional seconds for that part of the output.